Datasets tab not showing in Airflow
Using Airflow 2.10.2, connected with an admin role.
The Datasets tab is invisible.

The airflow instance contains dags with tasks that outlet datasets. There are no import errors and the datasets can be found in the airflow database.
Are there conditions for the Datasets tab to be displayed?

i'm having this same problem! did you ever resolve it?

Not yet, I just started a bounty to draw more attention.

We had this issue and the answer was to upgrade apache-airflow-providers-fab to version 1.5.0
The problem was reported in official repo: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/43685

That worked thank you. Can you please edit your answer to add the link to the issue in airflow? https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/43685
